# How to format text into a hyperlink in a text box of a python Kivy app

Tags: python, python-3.x, hyperlink, kivy

I want to output a URL (which is text) as a hyperlink to a text area of a Kivy application. How can I do such thing?

Comment: Could you post what you've tried already? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible with [RstDocument](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.rst.html) widget, but the widget isn't in a very good shape (a lot of things from RST syntax aren't implemented), so you'd need to handle it yourself with handling a collision with the word itself and some `on_release` event, otherwise it's just a simple text.

```
RstDocument:
    text: '`GitHub <https://github.com>`_'
```

A single step for implementing such behavior in `RstDocument` is this:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('https://github.com')
```

So, there are two ways how to do it - either implement collisions with the word and add a custom event, or make more `Label`s, where your link is in the separate label with a custom event. But this will need also resizing the area of the label, otherwise the whole area (not the string only) will launch the event:

```
#:import webbrowser webbrowser

<LinkLabel@ButtonBehavior+Label>:
    on_release: webbrowser.open(self.text)

LinkLabel:
    text: 'https://github.com'
    size_hint: None, None
    size: self.texture_size
    # fancy styling
    color: (0, 0, 1, 1)
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
```